# SSRS Exporting to Excel loses custom row height

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When exporting a SSRS report to excel the row height is not maintained. We have set the row height to be 0.17 Inches which would be 12.75pts, but when exporting to excel it is changing to 15pts.

We have tried the suggestions we could find on Google, which were to set CanGrow to false and canShrink to true but it still defaults to 15pts.

We have tried reducing the size even further, 0.10, 0.01 but it always goes to 15pts.

The font size is 10pts, which is correct, and is below the 12.75pts row height we are trying to achieve.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need both **CanGrow** and **CanShrink** set to `FALSE`.

Comment: That didnt work either. Have you ever been able to create a report that exports to excel with row heights less than 15?

Comment: Yes - I have one report with a row that I just checked that it **is working**. ALL the cells' (in this row) **CanGrow** & **CanShrink** are set to `FALSE`, the Font is `Calibri 5pt`, height is `.125"`. The row height exports as **9** in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'Vertical Alignment' to Bottom/Top.